# RTL8111/8168/8411 - Not Working on Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have this motherboard: [Prime B450M-Gaming/BR](https://www.asus.com/br/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-B450M-GAMING-BR) and the Ethernet Card is:

```
cetiberiojr@cetiberiojr-server:~$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 15
   serial: 04:d9:f5:75:fe:f9
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.03-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.0.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:59 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fcd04000-fcd04fff memory:fcd00000-fcd03fff
```

This Ubuntu Server is running my Media Server and after some time watching my series, the ethernet is abruptly going down. I'll only get connection again if I restart the system.

Following some guides, I blacklisted the `r8169` and installed the `r8168` from this link: [Realtek PCIe FE / GBE / 2.5G / Gaming Ethernet Family Controller Software](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software):

```
GBE Ethernet LINUX driver r8168 for kernel up to 5.6
```

My kernel is:

```
5.4.0-66-generic
```

Even after this r8168 installation, I'm still getting the same issues...

My `/var/log/syslog` when the problem happens:

```
Feb 26 22:51:55 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.092470] pcieport 0000:02:06.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 26 22:51:55 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.095935] pcieport 0000:02:05.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 26 22:51:55 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.099462] pcieport 0000:02:04.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 26 22:51:55 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.102979] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128355] enp7s0: cmd = 0xff, should be 0x07
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128355] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128360] enp7s0: io_base_l = 0xffff, should be 0xf001
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128360] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128409] enp7s0: mem_base_l = 0xffff, should be 0x4004
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128409] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128452] enp7s0: mem_base_h = 0xffff, should be 0xfcd0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128452] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128495] enp7s0: resv_0x1c_l = 0xffff, should be 0x0000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128495] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128538] enp7s0: resv_0x1c_h = 0xffff, should be 0x0000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128538] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128581] enp7s0: resv_0x20_l = 0xffff, should be 0x0004
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128581] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128624] enp7s0: resv_0x20_h = 0xffff, should be 0xfcd0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128624] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128667] enp7s0: resv_0x24_l = 0xffff, should be 0x0000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128667] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128710] enp7s0: resv_0x24_h = 0xffff, should be 0x0000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128710] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128753] enp7s0: ilr = 0xff, should be 0x05
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128753] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128795] enp7s0: resv_0x2c_l = 0xffff, should be 0x1043
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128795] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128833] enp7s0: resv_0x2c_h = 0xffff, should be 0x8677
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128833] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128998] enp7s0: pci_sn_l = 0xffffffff, should be 0x684ce000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.128998] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.130203] enp7s0: pci_sn_h = 0xffffffff, should be 0x01000000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.130203] .
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.131298] enp7s0: esd_flag = 0x7fff
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253344] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253356] WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 0 at /home/cetiberiojr/downloads/r8168-8.048.03/src/r8168_n.c:6911 rtl8168_wait_phy_ups_resume+0x5d/0x70 [r8168]
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253356] Modules linked in: r8168(OE) xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype iptable_filter iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 bpfilter br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs overlay nls_iso8859_1 dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm ccp snd_timer eeepc_wmi kvm asus_wmi snd sparse_keymap wmi_bmof k10temp joydev input_leds soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic amdgpu amd_iommu_v2 gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit usbhid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul hid ghash_clmulni_intel ttm aesni_intel drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect crypto_simd sysimgblt fb_sys_fops cryptd ahci
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253401]  glue_helper drm i2c_piix4 realtek libahci wmi video gpio_amdpt gpio_generic [last unloaded: r8169]
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253409] CPU: 5 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/5 Tainted: G           OE     5.4.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253410] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/PRIME B450M-GAMING/BR, BIOS 2807 02/01/2021
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253415] RIP: 0010:rtl8168_wait_phy_ups_resume+0x5d/0x70 [r8168]
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253418] Code: bf 58 89 41 00 89 c3 e8 c1 a5 6c d5 83 e3 07 66 44 39 eb 74 06 41 83 fe 63 7e cf 41 83 fe 64 74 09 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 <0f> 0b 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d c3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253419] RSP: 0018:ffffb7f60033cdb8 EFLAGS: 00010046
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253421] RAX: 00000a828f34c010 RBX: 0000000000000007 RCX: 0000000000000005
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253422] RDX: 0000000000366c48 RSI: 00000a828efe53c8 RDI: 00000000003664c6
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253424] RBP: ffffb7f60033cdd8 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253425] R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 00000000000000f0 R12: ffffa098da9008c0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253425] R13: 0000000000000003 R14: 0000000000000064 R15: ffffa098da900b18
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253427] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa098e0940000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253428] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253429] CR2: 0000000005595000 CR3: 00000004107c2000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253430] Call Trace:
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253432]  <IRQ>
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253438]  rtl8168_powerup_pll+0xad/0x120 [r8168]
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253443]  rtl8168_esd_timer.cold+0x20c/0x411 [r8168]
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253448]  ? rtl8168_open+0x440/0x440 [r8168]
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253452]  call_timer_fn+0x32/0x130
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253455]  __run_timers.part.0+0x180/0x280
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253459]  ? timerqueue_add+0x68/0xb0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253460]  ? enqueue_hrtimer+0x3d/0x90
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253463]  ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253465]  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253468]  __do_softirq+0xe1/0x2d6
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253470]  ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x13b/0x220
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253474]  irq_exit+0xae/0xb0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253476]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7b/0x140
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253477]  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253479]  </IRQ>
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253482] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xc5/0x450
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253484] Code: ff e8 ff aa 80 ff 80 7d c7 00 74 17 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 f6 c4 02 0f 85 65 03 00 00 31 ff e8 e2 16 87 ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 ed 0f 88 8f 02 00 00 49 63 cd 4c 8b 7d d0 4c 2b 7d c8 48 8d
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253485] RSP: 0018:ffffb7f60015fe38 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253487] RAX: ffffa098e096adc0 RBX: ffffffff973693c0 RCX: 000000000000001f
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253488] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00000000239f5802 RDI: 0000000000000000
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253489] RBP: ffffb7f60015fe78 R08: 000002e98db8fd87 R09: 00000000000025bb
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253490] R10: ffffa098e0969ac0 R11: ffffa098e0969aa0 R12: ffffa098ce03d400
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253491] R13: 0000000000000001 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffffa098ce03d400
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253494]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xa1/0x450
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253496]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253499]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253501]  do_idle+0x1dd/0x270
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253503]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253507]  start_secondary+0x167/0x1c0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253510]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Feb 26 22:51:58 cetiberiojr-server kernel: [ 3202.253512] ---[ end trace d914bcafafdcff1c ]---
```

I don't know what to do, I'm even thinking this could be a real hardware issue and exchange the motherboard for another one...

Comment: Have you tried the [r8168-dkms](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/r8168-dkms) package?

Comment: no, but will try, just install it?

Comment: I don't know how the realtek driver was installed. Uninstall it if possible, then `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`. Reboot.

Comment: I installed it using the ./autorun.sh, inside the tar file downloaded... how can I remove it?

Comment: Uninstall with: `sudo rmmod r8168; sudo rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8168.ko`